# When was the "Alexandrian period" of Greek sciences?

Tags: greece, alexander-the-great, alexandria

Engels ([1880](https://www.marxists.org/archive/marx/works/1880/soc-utop/ch02.htm)):

> The foundations of the exact natural sciences were, therefore, first worked out by the Greeks of the Alexandrian period, and later on, in the Middle Ages, by the Arabs.

When was this "Alexandrian period"?

---

The linked Marxists.org page says in a footnote:

> The Alexandrian period of the development of science comprises the period extending from the 3rd century B.C. to the 17th century A.D.

But I'm not sure if this is correct.

Comment: AFAIK Alexandrian period is actually the Hellenistic period. Not sure what the Marxists mean by it tho.

Comment: [Why question existing narrative?](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/922/1401)  Question title doesn't match question content.  What is wrong with [Wikipedia's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandrian_period?wprov=srpw1_0) answer? _why_ do you doubt that the provided answer is correct? What research have you done to confirm or deny your hypothesis?  Is there a reason you're asking the community to perform this research?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Approximately **300 BC to 30 BC**, or up to **642 AD.**

In the context of the sciences, the Alexandrian period refers to a phase associated with the [Musaeum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musaeum) at Alexandria - a institution which included the famous [Great Library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_of_Alexandria). Founded supposedly circa 300 BC by [Ptolemy I Soter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptolemy_I_Soter) and patronised by his dynasty until the Roman conquest, the Musaeum was a major centre for Hellenistic learning where the arts, philosophy and natural sciences flourished. These intellectual developments are collectively known as the [Alexandrian school](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandrian_school).

The period is commonly considered to have ended with the [Roman annexation of Egypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_of_Cleopatra) in 30 BC. However the Mauseum continued to operate for a while (though gradually replaced by the [Serapeum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serapeum_of_Alexandria)), and the city remained a centre of Graeco-Roman learning for centuries. Consequently, at an extreme, some writers puts the end of the Alexandrian period as late as the [Muslim conquest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siege_of_Alexandria_(641)).

The Marxist.org passage you cited comes from the works of Engels; I'm not sure why the dates he gave are off by a millennia, but perhaps he meant to say 7th century.

**Further Reading:** https://hekint.org/2017/01/22/philosophy-of-science-and-medicine-series-iv-alexandrian-period

Comment: What Engels means is the Alexandrian science was the pinnacle, only superseded at the end of medieval period 1453 (which is just "pitch dark" or the advent of modern natural science, epitomised with no more alchemy but chemistry http://www.mlwerke.de/me/me20/me20_456.htm

Comment: @LаngLаngС But 1453's not 17th century either.

Comment: Sure, but the chemistry cut-off vaguely fits; and I am not saying that what 'he means 'or his footnoters /interpreters 'say' is 'good' in this respect. (Since he argues with basic modes of production there as well, this materialist view of 'Alexandrian mode of knowledge production lasts (wasn't surpassed) until capitalist mode of knowledge production' is an opinion not entirely wrong but to  challenge easily. ;)

Comment: And btw in http://www.mlwerke.de/me/me19/me19_202.htm *Engels himself seems to agree more with your depiction* than with that footnote…

Comment: @LаngLаngС I had a similar thought, that "Alexandrian" was just being used as a synonym for pre-enlightenment, but the phrasing of "...and later on, in the Middle Ages..." makes that a pretty bad fit. I think the footnote is just wrong

Answer (score 1):

The more common name of this period is Hellenism. It starts with the death of Alexander III of Macedon (323 BC) and ends with the battle at Actium (31 BC).